# Component Stacking Error When Opening FileChooser

Tags: java, swing, menu, components, filechooser

I have a frame with some components and a menu. Certain buttons on the frame and in the menu open a JFileChooser (a new instance each time) to open and save files.

My problem is simple, whenever I open a JFileChooser in Java and press OK, the menu is hidden behind the other controls in the frame. This means that when I open the menu, some menu items cannot be displayed.

However, if I don't press OK in the JFileChooser but press cancel, this doens't happen. I assume there is some error in how the frame is repainted after the FileChooser get an "OK". As I said, the stacking of components seems to be faulty.

I didn't mix Swing and AWT components by the way. All my components are Swing components.

EDIT: Here is my code

```
final JFileChooser fileChooser = new JFileChooser();
fileChooser.setCurrentDirectory(new File(Books.getDirectory()));
fileChooser.setAcceptAllFileFilterUsed(false);
fileChooser.setFileFilter(new XmlFilter());
int returnVal = fileChooser.showOpenDialog(Main.this);
if (returnVal == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) {
// OK was pressed
}
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Do you set proper parent component to the JFileChooser ?

Comment: Code? Screenshots? Might make easier for us to see what is happening!

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).

Comment: @java-devil OK, I added the code I have right now. I can't access the instance of the frame as with the 'this' keyword because it's inside an actionPerformed() event handler. That's why I'm using Main.this.

Comment: Have `actionPerformed` call another method outside of the `ActionListener` so you can properly access the frame with `this`. This still doesn't show us what you mean by menu is hidden behind? And also if it was anything its the code within your condition which is causing the problem.